# Confirmation on list item click then follow href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm currently using Django in my template to generate `href` for each list element and on the `url`, a certain method is executed, removing the item from the list, however I'd like a confirmation box to appear to assure the user they wish to delete it.

The only issue is the `url` is dynamic, and changes for each element of the list using django variables, shown below:

```
    <div id="list5">
    <ul>
{% if results %}
  {% for result in results %}
<li><a href="/accounts/delete/{{result.0}}/{{result.1}}"><strong>{{result.0}}</strong>evaluating {{result.1}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<li><a href="#"><strong>Assessor</strong>evaluating Assessee</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

As a result, inline javascript onclick methods, and JQuery that I've been able to find on stack overflow doesn't seem to be working for me, is there a way I can generate a confirmation box (browser confirm is fine) on clicking of the list element, which then on a "yes" redirects and follows the `url` from the list element that the click was made from?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Why does JS not work for you? It would seem to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Why not add a class an id to each link.  Set the `$('.classname').click()` to essentially pull `$(this).attr('href')` and follow it if they click yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a setup like this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleter').click(function() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') == true) {
            window.open($(this).attr('goto'));
        }
    })
})
```

Template:

```
<div id="list5">
   <ul>
   {% if results %} 
   {% for result in results %}
      <li class='deleter' goto='/accounts/delete/{{result.0}}/{{result.1}}'><strong>{{result.0}}</strong>evaluating {{result.1}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Assessor</strong>evaluating Assessee</a></li>
   </ul>
   {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: When I select the row, nothing happens, no redirects and no link is followed

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded on the page?  Try going to your browser's console and see if there are any errors.